# How to get only the message from UnhandledException?

Tags: c#

I'm using the `UndhandledException` provided by the `AppDomain`, what I did is essentially this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
}

static void UnhandledExceptionTrapper(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   e.ExceptionObject.Message? <- there is no message
   Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("Press a key for exit.");
   Console.ReadLine();
   Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

how you can see I can't access to the message property, but if I set a break point I can see on the `e` variable the `Message` property, why I can't use this?

Comment: Maybe `if (e.ExceptionObject is Exception) { ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message; }`

Comment: Ah, so I need to cast it, let me try. Thanks for the hint !

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** do this.  Only e.ExceptionObject.ToString() produces a reasonable diagnostic that doesn't drop, say, an InnerException on the floor.

Comment: @HansPassant I know this, I'm just learning how the `AppDomain` raises the exceptions in the whole app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [ExceptionObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventargs.exceptionobject(v=vs.110).aspx) is an object. You can cast it to Exception in order to get the [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var exception = (e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
if (exception != null) 
{
   message =  exception.Message;
}
```

or MSDN suggests to cast it this way

```
Exception exception = (Exception) e.ExceptionObject;
var message = exception.Message;
```

Comment: @Rahul yes the first with `as` execute the cast only if the `ExceptionObject` is an exception. Seems working fine, thanks!

Comment: A strange situation happean, if I do. `Console.WriteLine("Message: " + message);` the message isn't printed. Instead, this working: `Console.WriteLine(message);`